# Передача столбцов из одного метода в другой в sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Друзья, нужна помощь

У меня есть несколько составленных таблиц и мне нужно формировать запрос к БД через sqlalchemy. Из таблицы мне нужны не все столбцы , а только несколько. Один метод у меня формирует столбцы из таблицы, а второй метод принимает эти столбцы, отправляет запрос по выбранным столбцам и уже возвращает данные из БД. Проблем заключается в том, что при передачи из первого метода во второй более чем одного столбца, сам столбец меняет свой тип.

Вопрос заключается в том как передать большое количество столбцов в правильном формате.

```py
# таблица
class CalculationTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'calculation_table'
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dating = Column(Date)
    pk_team = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('leads_team.pk'))
    processing_status = Column(String(20))
    pk_buyer = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('autorization.pk'))
    num_changes_in_table = Column(Integer)
    coming = Column(Numeric(6, 2))

# метод который возвращает нужные столбцы 
def columns_calculation_tabl():
    return CalculationTable.__table__.columns.dating, CalculationTable.__table__.columns.processing_status



def read(col):
    db_session = db_connect()
    line = db_session.query(col).all()
    db_session.commit()
    return line
```

Если возвращать из метода columns_calculation_tabl 2 столбца, то в результате получаем

```py
(Column('dating', Date(), table=<calculation_table>), Column('processing_status', String(length=20), table=<calculation_table>))
```

И данный результат не подходит для отправки запроса

А вот если передавать 1 столбце то возвращается тип данных который как раз и нужен

```py
calculation_table.dating
```

Надеюсь что есть выход из данной ситуации, потому что таблица большая (я отправил сюда сокращенную версию) да и запросов много. Каждый раз писать в запросе все столбцы в ручную это печальная история...